# Get/Set The Members of a Struct or a Class in a Class C#

Tags: c#, class, struct

If I have a `Struct` or a `Class`, lets say I'm using a Vector2 (which has two members, `float X` and `float Y`), how am I supposed to properly get/set its methods in  a class?

This is the code I know of right now:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Vector2 vector; //Has to be private
    public Vector2 Vector
    {
        get { return vector; }
        set { vector = value; }
    }
}
```

But what if I wanted to edit the members (or certain members) of the `Vector2` with the `set` method? Something like this is what I'm asking for:

```
set.X
{
    vector.X = value.X;
}
set.Y
{
    vector.Y = value.Y;
}
```

And it would be called as simply as `Vector.X = 5`. I thought up an alternative, using something like `public float VectorX { set { vector.X = value; } }` but I would prefer a more logical and object-orientated way. Is there?

Comment: Whats wrong with obj.Vector.X = 5?

Comment: How is your alternative not object-oriented? What do you mean by that?

Comment: [Mutable `struct`s are evil.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/441323/781792) If `Vector2` is a `struct`, rethink this.

Comment: What I meant by "not object orientated' is that it doesn't access its members with the method, I would prefer `Vector.X` to `VectorX`. With the alternative I have to write a new `get` and `set` for each member.

Comment: @TimS. Vector2 is a class of the XNA framework. That's a very interesting article though, I look forward to reading about it.

Comment: @mclaassen It will emit a compiler error because you're mutating a copy of the struct that you're just going to throw away.

Comment: @Servy You are absolutely right, if Vector2 is a struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes a BIG difference whether `Vector2` is a class or a struct.

Since `Vector2` is a class you can simply do

```
obj.Vector.X = 5;
```

having

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Vector2 _vector; //Has to be private
    public Vector2 Vector
    {
        get { return vector; }
        set { vector = value; }
    }
}
```

---

If, however `Vector2` *was* a struct then you cannot modify the return value from the `get`. If you try you will get a compile error:

> Cannot modify the return value of ... because it is not a variable.

You can work around this using the method you suggested with

```
public float VectorX
{
    get { return _vector.X; }
    set { _vector.X = value; }
}

public float VectorY
{
    get { return _vector.Y; }
    set { _vector.Y = value; }
}
```

or you could provide a wrapper class around `Vector2` like:

```
class Vector2Wrapper
{
    public Vector2 Vector;
}
```

and then store a `Vector2Wrapper` in `MyClass` like

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Vector2Wrapper _vector2Wrapper;
    public Vector2Wrapper VectorWrapper
    {
        get { return _vector2Wrapper; }
        set { _vector2Wrapper= value; }
    }
}
```

and you can then modify it like

```
obj.VectorWrapper.Vector.X = 5;
```

Comment: Thank you, this absolutely clears up any confusion that I had--I am used to writing in C++ and didn't take into consideration that classes are always references.

Answer (score 0):

you can't specify a submethod to handle that partial set, because that set is handled by the `Vector` class and us thus out of your scope. the moment someone calls `Myobject.Vector` they are calling your get funcion, but when it moves on to `.X` they are calling the `Vector.get_X` function.

This may be easier to see by looking at the compiled code using the [ILDasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) tool, which reveals the actual method calls your properties make sugar out of.

Now, what you CAN do is to *wrap* certain properties, as mentioned. The result would like like so.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Vector2 _vector; //Has to be private
    public Vector2 Vector
    {
        get { return vector; }
        set { vector = value; }
    }

    public float VectorX
    {
        get { return _vector.X; }
        set { _vector.X = value; }
    }

    public float VectorY
    {
        get { return _vector.Y; }
        set { _vector.Y = value; }
    }
}
```

Another option might be to use the pattern of [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) in your Vector class, raising an event every change which your MyClass can then listen to and react to, thus applying logic when child elements are updated.

There is also the option of using an indexer property

```
public class MyClass
{
    public enum Axis { X, Y }

    private Vector2 _vector; //Has to be private
    public Vector2 Vector
    {
        get { return vector; }
        set { vector = value; }
    }

    public float this[Axis axis]
    {
        get { return axis == Axis.X ? vector.x : vector.y; }
        set
        {
            if(axis == Axis.Y)
            {
                // Special logic here
                vector.Y = value;
            }

            if(axis == Axis.X)
            {
                // Special logic here
                vector.X = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had hoped this wasn't the case and that I was missing some basic syntax... Oh well.

Comment: Glad I could help, even if it wasn't the answer you wanted. I hope one of my alternatives helps, and I have one more to intefgrate to my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Because Vector2 is a struct, you are getting a COPY. You need to use the setter to set a new Vector2. There are 2 ways:

```
Vector2 v = myClass.Vector; //get a copy of the vector
v.X = 5f; // change its value
myClass.Vector = v; // put it back
```

I don't really like the following, but it's one statement:

```
    myClass.Vector = new Vector2(2f, myClass.Vector.Y)
```

Inside MyClass, you can create a property that sets only the X value:

```
public float X {
    get { return Vector.X; }
    set {
        Vector2 v = Vector;
        v.X = value;
        Vector = v;
    }
}
```

(Vector can be an automatic property)

Comment: Thank you, I know of that alternative as well but I was hoping for a way to use the same setter on each individual member.

Comment: You can create a property inside MyClass that sets whatever values you like.